# Should custom exceptions have their own ErrorCode?

Tags: c#

I've got a socket wrapper library I've been working on that handles, among other things, a little handshake at the beginning to ensure whoever you're talking to is using the same protocol and settings as you. I created my own exception class the standard way:

```
 private class NSocketProtocolException : System.Exception
    {
        public NSocketProtocolException(string message) : base(message) { }
    }
```

I throw this exception for a variety of reasons, like, if the client and server aren't using the same version of the protocol, if one wants to use encryption and the other doesn't, etc. Right now I'm the only one who uses this library, but I was trying to design it to be friendly enough so that maybe in the future other people could. In order for other programmers to be able to do something more worthwhile with the different instances where the exception would be thrown, should I have my own custom error codes to go with these?

I don't really know how to edit the error code, but more importantly, I don't want to use the same error code that maybe another type of exception uses. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need error codes, exception Message is the place for the details about exception. If you use error codes you will have to still document that error codes somewhere, right ? So that description can be in exception Message. Users of your code can catch exceptions by type.

If you need to store some data about exception or about context, use [Exception.Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), for example you could put in data Time Stamp of exception, or in web application you could put current request URL in Data etc.

Also be sure to read this blog post about [custom exceptions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/20/custom-exceptions-when-should-you-create-them.aspx), do you really need them ?

Comment: I'd like to think a custom exception is appropriate here. As a socket wrapper, it's supposed to behave the same as a socket, so the idea is it would throw an exception in the event that it cannot connect, just like how socket.connect would throw an exception for that reason. I don't want to throw a socketexception though, so the programmer has a better idea of what has gone wrong

Comment: OK, I didn't say that custom exception is inappropriate, just wanted to draw attention to that matter :)

Answer (score 1):

Just make the exception public, (add the other constructors), then if anyone who uses it feels the need for an error code in some downstream application that can't deal with exceptions they can add their own.

Comment: I meant, error codes to give details as to why the library itself is throwing the exception. So the programmer would have a way to know if the exception was thrown because of a bad protocol handshake, or if it was because the server only accepts encrypted connections

Comment: Error codes is things like Unknown oleError(5). If you want to add more data to an exception, as in Bad Handsake expected {0} received {1}, go right ahead. Compared to the usual "sumfin" messed up and I lost the stack trace as well, all will be golden.